# Randomize Alert Sound Effect in Mac OS

Tags: macos

Is there any way to randomize the alert sound effect in Mac OS? In system prefs I am able to select which sound effect I want to hear. Is there a way for the system to choose a random sound each time?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't built into macOS so this is something you are going to have to script and do a bit of customization.  You will need the following:

- Custom location for your sound
- Script to randomize the sound
- launchd plist to run the script at a set interval

#### Custom Location for Sound

System sounds are in the `/System/Library/Sounds` directory which I don't recommend attempting to modify.  You can copy them to `~/Libary/Sounds` or another custom directory of your choosing.  This way, you can add your own custom sounds without interfering with the System sounds themselves.

#### Script to Randomize Soundfile

The script below will generate a random number between 0 and the number of files you have in your sound directory.  It will then create an array of all the file names and then select a random filename (array element) which it will then copy that file to another file called `CustomAlert.aif`.  You can customize the filename and path to suit your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# script filename:  randomAlert.sh

#User Defined Variables
  sdir="/Users/foobar/test"
  sfname="CustomAlert.aif"


#Remove Custom Alert Sound if already Exists

  if [ -f ${sdir}/${sfname} ]; then
    rm -f ${sdir}/${sfname}
  fi



#Get Number of Files in Directory
  numfiles=(*)
  numfiles=${#numfiles[@]}


#Generate Random Number
  rnum=$(( $RANDOM % ${numfiles}  + 0 ))


#Put names of files into array
  fnames=(*)

#Copy file to Alert Sound File
  cp ${sdir}/${fnames[${rnum}]} ${sdir}/${sfname}

exit
```

Make sure the script's permissions is set to allow execution:

```
chmod +x randomAlert.sh
```

Finally, make sure the script is in a "safe" location (a folder in your home directory is always a good place)

#### Launchd plist

To have the script run, you need to use the `launchd` service.  The plist can go in any one of 3 locations:

- `~/Library/LaunchAgents` - For just one user, run as the user (i.e. yourself)
- `/Library/LaunchAgents` - For all users, run as the user
- `/Library/LaunchDaemons` - As a system daemon (run as root)

I recommend either of the first two; it doesn't make sense to run as a system daemon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.user.randomSound</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/USERNAME/Path_to_Scripts/randomAlert.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>00</integer>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>00</integer>
    </dict>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Once you have copied it to the appropriate directory, you need to launch it with `launchctl`

```
launchctl load com.user.randomSound.plist
```

#### Set your Alert Sound to the Custom File

In your settings, set the alert to `CustomAlert.aif`.  Even though the sound will change, the name of the file will stay the same.

That's it!  Every 24 hours, your script will kick off and set a new random alert sound.

Answer (score 0):

Bash and "Launchd plist" both sound very frightening to me...

So I came up with a solution that involves Python and a cron job instead.
(Shout out to the answer above and this other one: [Change default alert sound from terminal in Mac OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283791/264341))

---

I wrote a longer blog post explaining this in more details and using custom alert sounds:
[Randomizing the Alert Sound on a Mac](https://www.felixparadis.com/posts/randomizing-the-alert-sound-on-a-mac/)

But here's the TLDR:

#### 1- You can set the alert sound via the shell.

For instance, this:

`defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.sound.beep.sound /System/Library/Sounds/Sosumi.aiff`

Sets "Sosumi" as your alert sound.

#### 2- You can iterate over your sound files with Python and call the command from step 1.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess, random, glob

sounds = glob.glob('/System/Library/Sounds/*.aiff')
sound = random.choice(sounds)
print('randomly selected sound: ', sound)
command = 'defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.sound.beep.sound /System/Library/Sounds/{}.aiff'.format(sound)

# You could also define an array of sounds yourself,  
# if you don't want every .aiff file to be a possibility
# sounds=['sound1', 'sound2', 'sound3']
# sound=random.choice(sounds)
# command = 'defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.sound.beep.sound /System/Library/Sounds/{}.aiff'.format(sound)

subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

#### 3- You can call the Python script from step 2 with cron.

I use nano to edit my crontab file (but go ahead and use Vim or emacs if you're cool ).

`env EDITOR=nano crontab -e`

Assuming you named the script from step 2 "randomize.py", adapt the path and put this in your crontab file:

```
MAILTO=""
* * * * * python3 /Wherever/youWill/store/thisFile/randomize.py
```

Voilà! You now have a script that randomizes your alert sound every minute.
I run it every hour now, so `* * * * *` became `59 * * * *`.

Comment: I agree re bash - if it has more than 5 lines use a proper language but launchd is easy with a GUI like Launch Control