# Shortcut to multiple commands for cleanup

Tags: terminal, startup, shortcut, macos

To clean up cache and log files, I prefer to run following commands via terminal on daily basis (once a day, mostly in morning).

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/* ~/Library/Caches/*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Logs/* /Library/Caches/*
```

I want to make a shortcut for above commands. I was thinking of putting them into a file (say, `cleanup`) where above and other similar commands are listed on seperate lines. Wheneven, I want to run above commands, it should be simpler command like `run cleanup`.

Is this possible? Also, can I put something like this when system starts (post booting)?

Comment: Setting this as something that can be done is quite easy using `launchd`.  See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/314326/119271) and this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268692/119271) for more details.

Comment: I'm always interested in why people do things like this.  Can you comment on what problem you think this is solving?

Comment: @MarcWilson for cleanup purpose ;-) I assume that operating systems perform few level of clean up on its own. One of my friend who deals in computer hardware suggested me to cleanup logs and cache files regularly.

Comment: Take your friend out and beat him with a wet noodle.  Seriously.  The OS rotates logs.  Any OS does.  Or else it's broken, and then you fix it and move on.  As for the idea that you need to delete what's in a cache... <sigh>.  Does the word "counterproductive" mean anything to anyone?

Comment: Last comment... if whatever you're doing (for whatever value of "you", not just the OP), needs to have 'sudo' wrapped around it, think long and hard about whether you should be doing it in the first place.  Seriously.  Usually, the correct answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options to do this....

#### Create a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/* ~/Library/Caches/
sudo rm -rf /Library/Logs/* /Library/Caches/*
```

Assuming you've named it "cleanup" first make sure you set it to be executable:  `chmod +x cleanup`.

Then put it in one of the directories in your PATH by copying it or symlinking it:  `cp cleanup /usr/local/bin` or `ln -s ./cleanup /usr/local/bin/cleanup`

#### Make an alias

```
alias cleanup="rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/* ~/Library/Caches/; sudo rm -rf /Library/Logs/* /Library/Caches/*"
```

Put that alias in your `~/.bash_profile` so it's set every time you start a Terminal session.

Now that it's an alias, you can execute the command `cleanup` from Terminal and it will run those two commands.

Comment: Note the sudo will make the script ask for your password - better to set up the scripts in launchd. That will also allow you to automate when they run

Comment: @Allan - Thanks for your reply. When I checked contents of `.bash_profile`, I got following result --PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.8/bin:$PATH

Should I put alias on new line?

Comment: Yes.  Just put it on a separate line either above or below your `~/.bash_profile`